# "error: cannot find symbol" in Return Statement

Tags: java, scope

I'm trying to return a variable `String authServer`, but I can't seem to do it.

```
public static String getAuth () {
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = ConnectionConfig.getConnection();
        if (connection != null) {
            Statement query = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = query.executeQuery("SELECT auth FROM auth");
            while (rs.next()) {
                String authServer = rs.getString("auth");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return authServer;
    }
}
```

The code above gives me an error with unknown symbol "authServer".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You've declared authServer within the context of the while loop, making it inaccessible to the rest of the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `authServer` is declared in a loop above, it is not in scope when you try to use it in the return statement.

Java Made Easy has a nice [overview of variable scope in Java](https://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html#ixzz3curg6pRr) that should help you to understand the issue better.

In your specific case, consider the following modification to get around the issue:

```
public static String getAuth () {
    // Declare authServer with method scope, and initialize it.
    String authServer;
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = ConnectionConfig.getConnection();
        if (connection != null) {
            Statement query = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = query.executeQuery("SELECT auth FROM auth");
            while (rs.next()) {
                // Just assign to authServer here rather than declaring
                // and initializing it.
                authServer = rs.getString("auth");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return authServer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't declare authServer in the while loop. It's scope will end after the while loop. You need to declare outside the while loop.

```
public static String getAuth () {
    Connection connection = null;
    String authServer = "";
.....
```

Then retrieve the result from while loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring authServer inside while loop, making it inaccessible at the return statement.
Declare it after the connection statement like this:

```
Connection connection = null;
String authServer="";
```

And then use in the while loop as follows:

```
while (rs.next()) {
  authServer = rs.getString("auth");
}
```